# how routing connects to the page

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn angular with a book and some examples, and I have some difficult times trying to understand how the ng-view knows the view to display based on the routing system.

So here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="maintenance">
<head>
  <title>Dive Sites</title>
  <link href="./lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="./site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="adminCtrl">
  <!-- Navigation header -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#adminMenu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        Younderwater Admin
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="adminMenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ng-class="{active: isActive('Locations')}">
            <a href="#/locations">Locations</a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{active: isActive('Sites')}">
            <a href="#/sites">
              Dive Sites
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Optional title bar -->
<div class="current-spot">
    <div class="container-fluid" >
      <div class="container">
        <div ng-show="view=='locations'">
          <h3>Manage the list of diving locations</h3>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="view=='diveSites'">
          <h3>Manage the list of dive sites</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- View content -->
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="maintenance.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
angular.module('maintenance', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('adminCtrl', AdminCtrl)
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/locations', {
      templateUrl: 'views/locations.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/sites', {
      templateUrl: 'views/sites.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
    });
  });

function AdminCtrl($scope) {
}
```

I need to know if I have the correct way of thinking, watching this example, I would say that the '#' says to use the routing system, in the script we set the routes and the views the app should load based on the url, when I press the  because of the # it search based on the routing system and passes the view to the ng-view, I don't know if the processing is correctly thats why I need to understand better how it works, sorry if I don't explained very well :/

Ps: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost,  and angular.module('maintenance', ....) must match. I'm referring to the identifier 'maintenance'. Without this, your JS file won't find your HTML file.

From the JS file, you have angular.module('maintenance', ['ngRoute']), ngRoute is an angular directive for routing.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

The $routeProvider says what page to go to.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

And templateUrl shows the URL for the page.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

http://techfunda.com/howto/505/function-with-templateurl

I'm very sure you have the following html files in your project.

locations.html

sites.html

main.html